# Meteor map user to collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I have created an app that users can signup, login and create info. Each user can currently login and have access to notes he/she created. So basically, I created publish and subscription methods to handle.

I have an admin login that can view and update all the docs created by different users. Now I want to do it the other way round. I don't want for users to signup, the admin should create user accounts and create initial notes for them. Once login details is shared, user should be able to login, view, read and update info created by the admin user.

My struggle is, how do I map a user to a document, since they'll be created by the admin users?

Current user creation:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

export const validateNewUser = (user) => {
  const email = user.emails[0].address;

  new SimpleSchema({
    email: {
      type: String,
      regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    }
  }).validate({ email });

  return true;
};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Accounts.validateNewUser(validateNewUser);  
}
```

Doc creation

```
Meteor.publish("docs", function() {
    return Docs.find({ userId: this.userId });
  });

Meteor.methods({
  "docs.insert"(
    name,
    title,
    purpose
  ) {
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }
return Docs.insert({
      name,
      title,
      purpose
      userId: this.userId,
    });
  },
```

An admin user will create both user accounts and user info, how do I map user account to user info so that user can login and view info that was add for him?

Comment: In your admin panel you'll have a form to create new users. You'll also have a list of all users. Click a user in the list to view their notes. On this user-specific notes page you'll have a button "Add Note". Type your notes and "Save". In this scenario you've selected a user from the list so you'll know which user ID to associate with the notes you create. You can exit this context by returning to the user list where you can select another user to enter their context.

Comment: I thought about this solution. How will the saving be done on the server side? Will this be an update to the user collection? If not, how do you associate the userId with the doc then?

Comment: Each note document will need a `userId` key. The user collection doesn't need to be updated.

Comment: Correct. In my current doc, I'm saving as `userId: this.userId`. Any suggestion on how I can get the selected `userId`?

Comment: You can store it in a state variable when you select the user from the list. `this.state = { currentUserId: 123 }`